# Destructuring arguments to comparison operators

Tags: ruby, destructuring

Edited question: Does the Ruby syntax allow destructuring of Arrays in a nice way when using comparison operators?

Original question: Does the Ruby syntax allow destructuring of Arrays in a nice way?

For method calls one can use the Splat operator (*), but is it possible to do this without calling a method?

This is allowed:

```
foo = ['bar']
'bar'.==(*foo) # => true
```

Can this be written more similarly to this?

```
'bar' == *foo
# => *** SyntaxError Exception: (byebug):1: syntax error, unexpected *
# => 'bar' == *foo
```

Edit:
The question arose from code looking a little like this:

```
assert('test@example.com' == *email.to) # => Syntax error
assert_equal('test@example.com', *email.to) # => Success
```

Comment: No, using splat with operator syntax is not possible (as you see). 

BTW `'bar' == foo` is a method call.

Comment: `==` method takes only one argument, so with `foo` array containing more than 1 element it would fail not even because of syntax issue, but you'd try to call 1-argument method with more than 1 arguments. Sorry, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MarekLipka Basically this is the code I would like to have `assert('test@example.com' == *email.to)`, but I guess this is better anyway `assert_equal('test@example.com', *email.to)` (I deleted a comment that was an answer to something you said before an edit, where I answered that I did not want to assume the number of values in the email.to array). If you want to post this as an answer instead, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `'bar' == *foo` doesn't work is because the parser expects exactly **one** parameter for most operators (including the comparison operator). In the case of `'bar'.==(*foo)` the method still expects one parameter, but the parser doesn't see a problem, since you called it using a normal method call. To resolve this you could just call `#first` on the array: `'bar' == foo.first`

---

The reason this works for [`#assert_equal`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/test-unit/3.2.8/Test/Unit/Assertions#assert_equal-instance_method) is because elements of the `email.to` array are send as parameters.

However, if the array is empty you will get an argument error:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)

If the array contains more than 2 elements you will get the error:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 2..3)

If the array contains 2 elements the second element is used as error message in case of failure.

In conclusion you will only get the wanted result if the array contains exactly one element. This raises the question "Why use an array in the first place?" You could just use a normal variable, there is no reason to wrap it in an array (in the given context).

Comment: "If the array contains 2 elements the second element is used as error message in case of failure." This is a good point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo, = ['bar']
#⇒ ["bar"]
foo
#⇒ "bar"
```

There might be as many variables as needed.

```
foo, bar, *baz = %w|foo bar baz|
foo
#⇒ "foo"
bar
#⇒ "bar"
baz
#⇒ ["baz"]
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: The only question stated is “Does the Ruby syntax allow destructuring of Arrays in a nice way?” and the above perfectly answers it.